# Redux devTools shows difference in state, but React component won't update

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a React app with buttons that fetch recent bills and top donors for each Congress member. Both actions (fetchBillsByRep and getRepFinances) fetch correct data and correctly update Redux state. BUT. While fetching bills results in immediate re-render, fetching donors does not.

I have read more than a dozen answers to similar questions, and have tried the solutions. I am not mutating state; I always make a new copy. I am hitting debuggers where I expect to - and getting all values as expected.

inside MemberCard component, handleDonorsClick

```
  //donors
  handleDonorsClick = () => {
    let id = this.props.crp_id
    if (this.props.chamber === "senate"){
      this.props.getSenatorFinances(id)
    } else if (this.props.chamber === "house"){
      this.props.getRepFinances(id)
    }
    this.setState({ showDonors: true })
    debugger
    //showDonors = true
  }
```

HouseActions action creators: all values as expected:

```
export function fetchBillsByRep(id){
  return (dispatch) => {
      return fetch(API_BASE_URL+'/search/bills/member/'+id)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(bills => {
        if (!bills.error) {
          dispatch({type:"FETCH_BILLS_BY_REP", payload: { bills: bills, id:id}})
        } else {
          alert(bills.error.fullMessage)
        }
      }
    ).catch(error => alert(error))
  }
}

export function getRepFinances(id){
  return (dispatch) => {
      return fetch(API_BASE_URL+'/search/financial_disclosures/member/'+id)
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then(financialDisclosure => {
        if (!financialDisclosure.error) {
          dispatch({
            type:"GET_REP_FINANCES",
            payload: { financialDisclosure: financialDisclosure, id:id }})
        } else {
          alert(financialDisclosure.error.fullMessage)
        }
      }
    ).catch(error => alert(error))
  }
}
```

house.js reducer:
again, all values as expected

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type){

    case "SET_HOUSE":
        return action.house

  //<truncated>

    case "FETCH_BILLS_BY_REP":
      let bills = action.payload.bills
      let house = state.map(rep => {
        //find rep update bills
        if (rep.propublica_id === action.payload.id){
          rep.bills = bills
        }
        return rep
      }
    )
      return house

    case "GET_REP_FINANCES":
      let financialDisclosure = action.payload.financialDisclosure
      let house1 = state.map(rep => {
        if (rep.crp_id === action.payload.id){
          rep.financialDisclosure = financialDisclosure
          rep.donors = financialDisclosure.donors
        }
        console.log(rep.donors)
        return rep 
        //rep now has donors under rep.donors
      }
    )
      return house1
      //house1 is being returned as the new state for house
      //inside house1, rep has updated rep.donors
     default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

Redux DevTools State:Diff Tab after clicking get donors button:
(truncated, just showing top 2)

```
house
51
donors
0{
  "id": 621,
  "org_name": "Buchanan, Ingersoll & Rooney",
  "total": 21600,
  "pacs": 0,
  "indivs": 21600
}
1{
  "id": 622,
  "org_name": "Telacu",
  "total": 18900,
  "pacs": 0,
  "indivs": 18900
}
```

MemberCard component logic for deciding whether to render bills or donors:

```
       //format back of card
    let align
    let content
    let space
    if (this.state.showBills){
      image = ""
      align = "center"
      space = <br/>
      content =
      <>
       <MemberBills
        member={this.props}
        showBills={this.state.showBills}/>
        {hideBillsButton}
      </>
    } else if (this.state.showDonors){
      //debugger hits, this.state.showDonors = true
      image = ""
      align = "center"
      space = <br/>
      content =
      <>
        <MemberDonors
          member={this.props} showDonors={this.state.showDonors}/>
          {/*member has value, showDonors is true*/}
        {hideDonorsButton}
          {/*hideDonorsButton has value*/}
      </>
```

MemberDonors render:

```
<div>
        <br/>
        <hr/>
        <h4 className="center">Top Three Donors</h4>
        {popUpNotice}
        {donorList}
        {/* donorList has correct values */}
        <br/>
        {donorsSource}
        {/* donorsSource has correct values */}
        <br/>
        <br/>
      </div>
```

I don't get any errors. Instead, I get the MembersDonors view, showing "Top Three Donors", the popUp notice ... but no donorList. However, if I refresh the page, find that particular Member again, and re-click the showDonors button, the donors appear.

I am following the same pattern I used for fetching and showing bills.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show your reducer in its entirety, but I bet it's because you are mutating your state, not creating a new version.

```js
a = {}
b = a
b.d = 10
console.log(a)
console.log(b)
console.log(a === b)
```

What you need is to return a new copy of your state, which can be done using `Object.assign` or the spread operator

```js
a = {}
b = {...a}
b.d = 10
console.log(a)
console.log(b)
console.log(a === b)
```

So in short, the easiest way to fix your code is to make a copy in your `return` statement for all of your cases.

```
return {...rep}
```

Comment: wow, thx for fast response - i edited to show better  copy of my reducer (with middle truncated). I tried return {...rep} and that does not change the behavior.

Comment: So sorry. Misread your reducer. I looked through it and the only possible discrepancy that might be problematic are your conditionals in the component. Your code hits the `debugger` but is the value of `this.state.showDonors` what you expect after your redux store updates? This looks like something you have to manually update, since this is in local state (`this.state`)

Comment: Thanks again. (You weren't seeing things, I updated reducer after your first comment). Yes, this.state.showDonors shows true in debugger. Or maybe you mean showDonors value isn't updating on time?

Comment: I added another code snippet -   handleDonorsClick. it sets state to showDonors after button is clicked, and it seems to be working, see code above.